# How to disable focus on Swiper Pagination bullets when clickable

Tags: accessibility, swiper.js, keyboard-navigation, react-swiper

I'm using Swiper with the Pagination module, I added a tab index to an anchor inside each card and I want the user to be able to **use keyboard navigation on the anchors themselves**.

My issue is that **if I set the bullets to be clickable (which I want) I also get a tab index set to zero on each bullet** and the keyboard experience becomes very confusing.

I tried using the *renderBullet* prop to pass a custom template, but it seems the tab index is added by some javascript in the library:

```
...
pagination={ {
  clickable: true,
  renderBullet: function (index, className) {
    return `<span class="${className}" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide ${index + 1}"></span>`;
    }
} }
...
```

Since this is somehting done by the library, **how can I configure Swiper to make make the pagination bullets not focusable** (or at least how can I reasonably disable them without forking the library)?